# Type error when trying to execute little game code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code a little game here to show someone, but I'm having trouble with it. When I try a sum of two values, it just says `TypeError: must be str, not int`. I am newbie, so I wasn't able to find a fix. 
I programmed it in another language (not another programming language, I mean I programmed it in portuguese but translated it to english so it is easier to understand).
Here you have the code:

```
import random
import time

print ('Welcome to the Even or Odd game!')
print ('Type the letter \'o\' if you want odd and \'e\' if you want even.')

userChoice = input('Your choice: ').lower()
time.sleep(1)
userNumber = input('Now, type in a number from 1 to 5: ')

randomNumber = random.randint(1,5)
time.sleep(2)

print ('Your number: ' + str(int(userNumber)))
time.sleep(2)
print ('Computer\'s number: ' + str(int(randomNumber)))
time.sleep(2)

result = userNumber + randomNumber
print ('Adding these two numbers together, you have ' + str(result))
if result % 2 == 0:
    if userChoice == 'e' or 'even':
        print ('You won!')
    else:
        print ('You lost!')
else:
    if userChoice == 'o' or 'odd':
        print ('You won!')
    else:
        print ('You lost!')
```

I get the TypeError if I run this program. It happens when it tries to execute `result = userNumber + computerNumber`.
Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/2301450

Comment: Thank you vaultah, I am sorry, I should've looked deeper. I won't do it again, I promise! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take the user's input, it is being stored as a string. You're getting the error because you're trying to add a string and an integer.

You can use the int() function to turn a string to an integer. So you can do for example:

```
result = int(userNumber) + int(randomNumber)
```